What is Video recording capability name in Selenium Grid 4
In Selenium Grid 3, to record the video in remote Selenium Grid, the following code was used:
capabilities.setCapability("name", "PRELIVE: FOFC Attachments"); capabilities.setCapability("node_screen_recording", "true");
This resulted in the remote Selenium Grid to have a video with the name: PRELIVE: FOFC Attachments as in the image below:

Certain requirements forced me to migrate to Selenium 4.
Now, I am using Selenium Grid 4.18.0. The automation script version is: <selenium-java.version>4.19.0</selenium-java.version>.
I am using the following code to ensure that the remote video is being recorded and giving it a name (testInstanceName):
Map<String, Object> cloudOptions = new HashMap<>();                                  cloudOptions.put("name", testInstanceName);                                         chromeOptions.setCapability("cloud:options", cloudOptions);                        chromeOptions.setCapability("se:recordVideo", true);
But with the above code, the testInstanceName is not being set to PRELIVE: FOFC Attachments nor the video nor any logs on the Right Hand Side being recorded as in the image below:
.
The remote Selenium Grid 4 nodes run on Linux 5.14.21-150500.55.44.
cloudOptions.put("name", testInstanceName);                                         chromeOptions.setCapability("cloud:options", cloudOptions);                        chromeOptions.setCapability("se:recordVideo", true);
se:recordVideo being set to true I found this here on Stackoverflow itself.
Can anyone please let me know what capability name I need to add to ensure that the video recording happens and also the test instance name is displayed?
